# Запятая перед союзом «и» в ССП

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, ссп

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом «и»?
Является ли фраза «с июля по апрель» обобщающим членом предложения?

Я тоже с июля по апрель сижу на диване(,) и чего-то не происходит ничего

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Я тоже с июля по апрель сижу на диване, и чего-то не происходит ничего.***

1. **Порядок слов здесь ничего не изменит**  – общий член предложения может находиться  и в середине ССП, например: Засвищут скоро соловьи   и лес оденется листвою. Ветер к утру ослабел   и снег престал. Гонятся над лугом друг за другом стрекозы   и перепархивают бабочки.
2. В этом предложении надо поставить **запятую** (хотя для окончательного решения  желательно видеть  контекст):

***Я тоже с июля по апрель сижу на диване, и почему-то не происходит ничего.*** В данном случае просматривается **противительное значение союза**  (И в значении НО),  а предложения имеют **собственные распространители.**  Две части ССП сложно объединить и прочитать в одну фразу, а именно в этом состоит смысл общего элемента, который определяет отсутствие  запятой.

3. Сравнить: ***Целый день** сидел дома и ничего не происходило, но стоило выйти, как сразу всё началось.*   Здесь общий член действительно объединяет предложения.